# Debugging "he's dead, Jim!" error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working on a JS plugin. After adding some lines of code, I'm experiencing crashes in Chrome in certain situations, seeing a ["he's dead, Jim" message](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1270364?hl=en) after I kill the page. It means I have run out of memory, which probably means an infinite loop or the like.

I don't need help with the JS, that isn't what I'm asking. What I want to see is the traceback. I went to `~/.config/google-chrome/CrashReports/` (I'm using Ubuntu), but it's empty. I Googled around and tried using `locate` in terminal but couldn't find anything relevant (Google's troubleshooter mostly focuses on the user end experience, less on the developer end, so it isn't helpful).

I know I can use breakpoints and stuff, but I'd love to see the traceback too, and I also want to know the general process for debugging these sort of crashes (I won't always know what part of the code generated the crash, it's by pure chance that I happened to find it right away this time).

Comment: Infinite loops don't always generate infinite amounts of data. Imho more likely is some kind of memory leak.

Comment: @Bergi point taken. Though it doesn't take me any further in debugging this (I should mention that the page crashes even when using breakpoints so getting the traceback is really important for me)

Comment: I understand, but I fear most crashes - which seem to happen when allocating memory - are not directly triggered from a line of javascript code, but rather from background-arriving resources (images, xhr, …) so that there might not be js stacktrace at all

Comment: @Bergi I don't know about most cases, but I do know my js is responsible in this case. I've added one functionality (which closed a container when clicking escape), and then I test drove it. When pressing escape after doing this and that, it crashes the tab. This doesn't happen if I comment the line and isn't related to any XHR request in the background (because there isn't any).

Comment: Have you tried surrounding the offending line in a try/catch and printed the trace to the console or in a `window.alert(trace);`? You might look at http://www.codeovertones.com/2011/08/how-to-print-stack-trace-anywhere-in.html for more information about how to do this. Hope it helps. C§

Comment: The page that you link to mentions `Aw, Snap!` rather than `he's dead, Jim!`. Can you please correct the inconsistency? (In particular: if Chrome is actually saying `Aw, Snap!` and not `he's dead, Jim!`, then while I appreciate that you're trying to be clever, the real effect is that your question is not searchable, and therefore not useful.)

Comment: @ruakh if you google a little you''ll see both of these are [referred interchangeably](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/chrome/8PoBurVMNko), which leads me to believe they changed the error name or unified the doc pages (the one I linked). Since this has to be a recent change, using the old one doesn't actually effect the searchability so for now I'd leave it like that)

Answer (score 1):

Go to profile tab on developer console. Take a heap snapshot. By default it will show summary view. You can take two snapshot at different time and switch the comparison view. If you see any object with unusual delta or allocated size. This might be useful to find which object is getting created and not getting destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Chromium command line switches to show debug infos?

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/